# How to import a node.js module into a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules

I'm refactoring my code from one big browser javascript file into a nicer node JS structure, with webpack, and I'd really like to be able to import the OpenLayers node module into my node scripts.

My JS files and package.json are stored in `/mymodule`, and the node_modules folder for my project is in `/node_modules` - I have a symlink set up to `/mymodule` from `/node_modules/mymodule`. My `/mymodule/index.js` file loads a bunch of other files into which I've been refactoring my code from my original browser javascript.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mymodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Description goes here",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "bundledDependencies": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "ol": "6.5.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my index.js:

```
const myConstants = require('./myConstants.js')
const myHelpers = require('./myHelpers.js')
const myStats = require('./myStats.js')
const myStyles = require('./myStyles.js')

module.exports = Object.assign({}, myConstants, myHelpers, myStats, myStyles)
```

And this is where I'm having issues - myStyles.js:

```
import { Style, Circle, Stroke, Fill, Text } from 'ol/style';

exports.image = new Circle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'red',
    width: 1,
  }),
});
```

I ran `npm install`, and that created a new `/mymodule/node_modules` folder, with OpenLayers installed in an `/ol` folder in there. Something tells me that was not the right way to do things, because I was expecting my module to just load OpenLayers from the existing `/node_modules/ol` installation rather than making a new `/mymodule/node_modules/ol` installation. I was hoping that setting `"bundledDependencies": false` in package.json would achieve that, but I guess not.

`npm run dev` goes ahead and completes without any errors, but then in the browser console I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` at this line:

```
exports.image = new Circle({
```

... in fact that line above has been rewritten by webpack (I assume) as follows:

```
exports.image = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_ol_style__["a" /* Circle */]({
```

Everything else I've done so far with other exports from my other JS files (myConstants.js, myHelpers.js etc) has worked just fine, so I'm sure I'm just doing this import process the wrong way. But what am I actually doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mixing ESM and CommonJS, unfortunately you can not use both, you must use one or the other.

You want to use the Export keyword rather than module.exports/exports

```js
import { Style, Circle, Stroke, Fill, Text } from 'ol/style';

export const image = new Circle({
  radius: 5,
  fill: null,
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'red',
    width: 1,
  }),
});
```

This will allow you to `import {image} from "filename"`

**Note** - as Jackie said, This will only work for node>=13.x

In node <12  you must add the flag `--experimental-modules` and use .mjs file extension

Comment: Also make sure you are using the --experimental-modules flag and the file has an extension .mjs.

Comment: Since v13 this is actually not experimental anymore, and there is no more flag.

Comment: Lol ok sorry been on pre since 12 but still should be sure to denotate the Module system (IE cjs, mjs, etc) in the extension

Comment: So I guess first question is what version of node is he using.

Comment: I'll modify my answer to account for that @Jackie

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I'm using Node 12.16.1. Silly question but where do I put the --experimental-modules flag?

Comment: The flag is added After node: `node  --experimental-modules app.mjs`

Comment: This fixed the issue, after I updated to the latest stable node version (v14.17.0). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `module.exports` and `exports`. Since `exports` is a variable referring to `module.exports`, and it seems to not be available in the browser, use `module.exports` instead of `exports`.

This

```js
exports.image = new Circle({
```

would become this :

```
module.exports.image = new Circle({
```

Comment: ESM modules may not assign module.exports, that is CommonJS, this is ESModules. The proper syntax is `export OBJECT`

Comment: @EthanSnow Webpack supports CommonJS modules

Comment: Correct, however he is using ESM Imports, if was using require then yes, he could use module.exports. You can't mix the two in a single file.

Comment: @EthanSnow Look at the first line of his `index.js`, he is `require`-ing `myStyles.js` and not importing it, so the functionality should be exposed *via* `module.exports`.

Comment: I stand corrected, I was unaware of that functionality and I learned something today, thank you. However it's still good practice to stay within the module system of the file.

Comment: OK from the above comments I'm wondering if I should be using require rather than import - I'm using webpack. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @GarethJones I think `require` is more used in Node.js